# Kafka consumer api in java has to fetch message based on offset

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a requirement that the consumer should be able to go back to any point of message stream and reprocess the message.

It looks like to set an offset in High level consumer as it needs setting offset in the zookeeper and re-start of  consumer is needed.

Simple consumer supports this ,but need to handle broker leader election ,broker leader failure etc.

The new consumer api provide this ,but it looks like this is still in beta.

So we might have to select simple consumer. Any know issues with simple consumers

Comment: Just the one you already mentioned -- that you have to handle leader election changes on your own. There's lots of code out there that shows you how to do this, however.